# Go to the last cursor position using marks

Tags: mark

I like to add marks for move across files but most of the time, I don't care about the line. I want to go on the last position of the cursor.

For example, I have this marks :

```
:marks
mark line  col file/text
 '      1    0 class ContentsController < ApplicationController
 C    350    4 @content.attributes = @content.default_attributes
 M    387    2 app/models/content.rb
 V      3    0 app/views/contents/index.html.erb
```

So `g'M` will move to `app/models/content.rb` on the last cursor position.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The mark `"` indicates the position of the cursor when you last exited a buffer. Using that...

Continue to use your cross-file marks but immediately follow with `'"` (or `` `" `` to restore the column as well as the line):

```
'X'"
```

To make it a bit more convenient you can create a mapping that does the same thing:

```
:nnoremap <leader>'X 'X'"
```

If you put this in a function so you can do the double-jump with any mark:

```
func! Jump2(mark)
    exec "norm! '" . a:mark . "'\""
endfunc
```

To run it `:call Jump2('X')`. A user command and/or mapping can shorten things.

Taking things further, see `:help last-position-jump`

```
    This autocommand jumps to the last known position in a file
    just after opening it, if the '" mark is set: >
:au BufReadPost * if line("'\"") > 1 && line("'\"") <= line("$") | exe "normal! g`\"" | endif
```

If you instead used `BufEnter`/`BufWinEnter` then each time you switch to a different buffer you'll start at the last known position. That may be more than you had in mind but you can easily add logic to the `autocommand` so it only occurs under certain conditions.

That's just a few things that come to mind. Really, "the possibilities are limited only by your imagination!" ;)

*Note: Mark `"` might not always be set...but from a practical standpoint it usually will be.*